# Как вывести A.K. с помощью кода с union?

Tags: c++, union

Дали код с заданием дополнить его, чтобы `cout` выводило `A.K.`. Вот сам код:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

union Data {
    int i;
    char c;
};

int main()
{
    Data myBite;
    myBite.i = 65;
    cout << myBite.c;

    return 0;
}
```

Не могу понять, что мне надо сделать. Вроде как `char` может содержать только 1 символ, однако, массив `char[]` может содержать несколько. Только вот как мне сделать массив из этого?
Я вообще впервые вижу какой-то `union`, поэтому даже не предполагаю, что с ним делать.

Обновлено:
Друзья скинули ещё вариант реализации такого.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    cout << "START\n";
    union Data
    {
        int i;
        char c;
    };

    Data myByte;
    myByte.i = 65;
    cout << myByte.c;
    myByte.i = 46;
    cout << myByte.c;
    myByte.i = 75;
    cout << myByte.c;
    myByte.i = 46;
    cout << myByte.c << endl;
}
```

Comment: Что значит "дополнить код"? Если я допишу в main `std::cout << "A.K."; return 0;` - я же "дополнил код"?

Comment: Ну по факту я также подумал, но мне сказали, что надо преобразовать переменные, данные в union.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Data myBite = {0};
myBite.c = 'k';
myBite.i <<= 8;
myBite.c = 'A';    
char* p = &d.c;   
cout << *p++ << *p; //вывод: AK
```

Дело в том, что `myBite.c` находится по тому же адресу, что и  `myBite.i`, символ занимает 1 байт, а второе(int) - 4 байта. Остается лишь инициализировать эти байты правильно. С помощью битового свига мы этого можем добиться, а адрес на символ будет указателем на начало  этого "4_х байтного массива ". Более того, можно получить и 4 символа:

```
Data d = {0}; 
d.i = 'A';
d.i |= '.'<< 8;
d.i |= 'K'<< 16;
d.i |= '.' << 24;
char* p = &d.c;
for (int i = 0; i < 4; ++i)
    cout << *p++ ; //вывод: A.K.
```

Comment: Это если повезёт и следующий байт за интом будет 0 (чтение которого UB вроде как)... К тому же, сначала надо инициализировать инт, `d.i = 0;` первым делом сделать, потому что опять же, может не повезти...

Comment: Drawn Raccoon,  а вот член  объединения нужно инициализировать с самого начала _ при определении объединения,(структуры, класса),  Вы правы,

Comment: Пока не получилось... Хотя сделал всё как Вы расписали. Не могу понять, почему.
Обн: Вроде вышло, но после последней точки символы непонятные... ╠╠╠╠1╩БП\√╧

Comment: а вы точно обнулили  Data ::i как показано в начале? Ладно, смотрите обновление.

Comment: Причем тут нулевой символ? Тут нет массива символов, чтобы  закончить нулевым символом. Это просто последовательности байтов.  Просто нужно читать столько, сколько нужно.  Я для краткости написал вывод так, а по хорошему нужно как сейчас я вам показал.

Comment: да, я занят,  не внимательно прочитал ваш коммент. Если вы все это понимаете, почему самому не исправить просто?...

Comment: Всё, спасибо, не очень понял, почему обнулять обязательно, как так выходит, что там что-то есть до обнуления? Но всё сделал и всё работает, очень хитро...

Comment: KoryJaxx,  в первом варианте, когда  я инициализировал `char,` а не `int,`  остальные биты  `int` а могут все еще содержать мусор, содержащийся в памяти выделенной для `Data`,  поэтому сначала нужно обнулить. Во втором варианте не нужно, потому что `d.i`  сразу инициализирован . Просто я немного небрежно написал с самого начала, как это верно заметил   `Drawn Raccoon` .